# Competitor Web Keywords

Tags: seo, google-analytics, search-engines

I am working on my SEO and have looked over my own keyword traffic through Google Analytics, but is there a way to see the **traffic competitors get** from a particular keyword?

For example, if I get 200 hits for "house cleaning," I don't actually know if that's good or bad until I see my competitors...if they get 1,000 hits from that term, we're doing horribly, but if they only get 10 hits, we're doing great.

Thanks

(and yes, i know how to `view source` to see their `meta tags`, but i want to actually see the numbers they are getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John writes you will not be able to see the traffic your competitors get. But you can get some estimations by using the tools Google provides.

With Google'S AdWords [keyword tool](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool&ei=xkBcUYzZBInIhAfEhYHQBw&usg=AFQjCNGMj3CYoZGzwNtWB6InzNCLcvkMhA&sig2=OeRCLf0bqhf7TtnuCUKJqw&bvm=bv.44697112,d.ZG4) you can see how much traffic is on a specific keyword. You can narrow it to your country/location as well. For "house cleaning" there are over 800,000 search requests per month.

Using Google's [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) you can see on how many searches your website shows up and also see the average position. For each position up you can almost double the CTR ...

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way to know this is to have access to their site stats (Google Analytics, Awstats, etc). You obviously don't have this.